# Error using Gradle importing spring-integration-kafka

Tags: java, spring, gradle, spring-boot, spring-integration

My gradle.build script looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/simple/ext-release-local' }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.1.9.RELEASE")

    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'application'



jar {
    baseName = 'calc-service'
    version = '0.1.0'
}

ext {
    springBootVersion = '1.1.9.RELEASE'
    springIntegrationVersion = '4.0.3.RELEASE'
    springIntegrationKafkaVersion = '1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/public'
    }
    maven { url 'https://repo.springsource.org/libs-milestone' }


}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    compile 'org.projectreactor.spring:reactor-spring-context'
    compile 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'


    //SI
   // compile "org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:$springIntegrationVersion"
    compile "org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-stream:$springIntegrationVersion"


    compile 'org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-mongodb:4.0.4.RELEASE'


    //kafka
    compile("org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-kafka:$springIntegrationKafkaVersion") {
        exclude module: 'log4j'
        exclude module: 'jms'
        exclude module: 'jmxtools'
        exclude module: 'jmxri'
    }

    compile("log4j:log4j:1.2.15") {
        exclude module: 'mail'
        exclude module: 'jms'
        exclude module: 'jmx'
        exclude module: 'jmxtools'
        exclude module: 'jmxri'
    }
    compile "commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1"

    //Required dependency for JSP
    providedRuntime 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper'

    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:$springBootVersion")
    testCompile("junit:junit")
}






task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.11'
}
```

I get this error:

```
Warning:<i><b>root project 'CalcMicroService': Web Facets/Artifacts will not be configured</b>
Details: org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolveException: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':runtime'.
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-kafka:1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.
Required by:
    :CalcMicroService:unspecified
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resource.ResourceException: Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://repo.springsource.org/libs-milestone/org/springframework/integration/spring-integration-kafka/1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml.
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not GET 'https://repo.springsource.org/libs-milestone/org/springframework/integration/spring-integration-kafka/1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml'.
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated</i>
```

struggeling this for hours
Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are pulling in a snapshot, you need to use the snapshot repo: http://repo.spring.io/snapshot/ instead of the release repo (which should really be http://repo.spring.io/release/).

However, I recommend you use the current milestone (1.0.0.M2) and use the milestone repo: http://repo.spring.io/milestone/

Comment: Thanks that work. I got other issues now. wish I could have working example of this somewhere.

Comment: [Spring XD](http://projects.spring.io/spring-xd/) has kafka [source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/tree/master/modules/source/kafka/) and [sink](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/tree/master/modules/sink/kafka/) modules that use the adapters.

Comment: I tried this with Spring Integration which using same configuration as Spring XD. still the producer never worked. I created new question at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27147241/spring-integration-kafka-adaptor-not-producing-message    please take a look. thanks.