# Spring-Kafka Integration 1.0.0.RELEASE Issue with Producer

Tags: spring-integration, apache-kafka

I am not able to publish message using Spring Kafka Integration, though my Kafka Java Client is working fine.

The Java code is running on Windows and Kafka is running on Linux box.

```
 KafkaProducerContext<String, String> kafkaProducerContext = new KafkaProducerContext<String, String>();
    ProducerMetadata<String, String> producerMetadata = new ProducerMetadata<String, String>("test-cass");
    producerMetadata.setValueClassType(String.class);
    producerMetadata.setKeyClassType(String.class);
    Encoder<String> encoder = new StringEncoder<String>();
    producerMetadata.setValueEncoder(encoder);
    producerMetadata.setKeyEncoder(encoder);

    ProducerFactoryBean<String, String> producer = new ProducerFactoryBean<String, String>(producerMetadata, "172.16.1.42:9092");

    ProducerConfiguration<String, String> config = new ProducerConfiguration<String, String>(producerMetadata, producer.getObject());
    kafkaProducerContext.setProducerConfigurations(Collections.singletonMap("test-cass", config));
    KafkaProducerMessageHandler<String, String> handler = new KafkaProducerMessageHandler<String, String>(kafkaProducerContext);
    handler.handleMessage(MessageBuilder.withPayload("foo")
            .setHeader("messagekey", "3")
            .setHeader("topic", "test-cass")
            .build());
```

I am getting following error

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin\java" -Didea.launcher.port=7542 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.6\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\jre\lib\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\projects\SpringCassandraInt\target\classes;C:\Users\hs\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-cassandra\1.1.2.RELEASE\spring-data-cassandra-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\hs\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-cql\1.1.2.RELEASE\spring-cql-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\hs\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\4.1.4.RELEASE\spring-context-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\hs\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\4.1.4.RELEASE\spring-aop-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\hs\.m2\repository\aopalliance\aopalliance\1.0\aopalliance-1.0.jar;C:\Users\hs\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\4.0.9.RELEASE\spring-beans-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\hs\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\4.1.2.RELEASE\spring-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\hs\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.3\commons-logging-1.1.3.jar;C:\Users\hs\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\4.1.2.RELEASE\spring-expression-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\hs\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\4.1.4.RELEASE\spring-tx-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\hs\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\1.9.2.RELEASE\spring-data-commons-1.9.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\hs\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.10\slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar;C:\Users\hs\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jcl-over-slf4j\1.7.10\jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.10.jar;C:\Users\hs\.m2\repository\com\datastax\cassandra\cassandra-driver-dse\2.0.4\cassandra-driver-dse-2.0.4.jar;C:\Users\hs\.m2\repository\com\datastax\cassandra\cassandra-driver-core\2.0.4\cassandra-driver-core-2.0.4.jar;C:\Users\hs\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty\3.9.0.Final\netty-3.9.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\hs\.m2\repository\com\codahale\metrics\metrics-core\3.0.2\metrics-core-3.0.2.jar;C:\Users\hs\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\15.0\guava-15.0.jar;C:\Users\hs\.m2\repository\org\liquibase\liquibase-core\3.1.1\liquibase-core-3.1.1.jar;C:\Users\hs\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.13\snakeyaml-1.13.jar;C:\Users\hs\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.1.2\logback-classic-1.1.2.jar;C:\Users\hs\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.1.2\logback-core-1.1.2.jar;C:\Users\hs\.m2\repository\org\springframework\integration\spring-integration-core\4.1.2.RELEASE\spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\hs\.m2\repository\org\projectreactor\reactor-core\1.1.4.RELEASE\reactor-core-1.1.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\hs\.m2\repository\com\goldmansachs\gs-collections\5.0.0\gs-collections-5.0.0.jar;C:\Users\hs\.m2\repository\com\goldmansachs\gs-collections-api\5.0.0\gs-collections-api-5.0.0.jar;C:\Users\hs\.m2\repository\com\lmax\disruptor\3.2.1\disruptor-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\hs\.m2\repository\io\gatling\jsr166e\1.0\jsr166e-1.0.jar;C:\Users\hs\.m2\repository\org\springframework\retry\spring-retry\1.1.1.RELEASE\spring-retry-1.1.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\hs\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-messaging\4.1.4.RELEASE\spring-messaging-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\hs\.m2\repository\org\springframework\integration\spring-integration-stream\4.1.2.RELEASE\spring-integration-stream-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\hs\.m2\repository\org\springframework\integration\spring-integration-xml\4.1.2.RELEASE\spring-integration-xml-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\hs\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-oxm\4.1.4.RELEASE\spring-oxm-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\hs\.m2\repository\org\springframework\ws\spring-xml\2.2.0.RELEASE\spring-xml-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\hs\.m2\repository\com\jayway\jsonpath\json-path\1.2.0\json-path-1.2.0.jar;C:\Users\hs\.m2\repository\net\minidev\json-smart\2.1.0\json-smart-2.1.0.jar;C:\Users\hs\.m2\repository\net\minidev\asm\1.0.2\asm-1.0.2.jar;C:\Users\hs\.m2\repository\asm\asm\3.3.1\asm-3.3.1.jar;C:\Users\hs\.m2\repository\org\springframework\integration\spring-integration-kafka\1.0.0.RELEASE\spring-integration-kafka-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\hs\.m2\repository\org\apache\avro\avro-compiler\1.7.6\avro-compiler-1.7.6.jar;C:\Users\hs\.m2\repository\org\apache\avro\avro\1.7.6\avro-1.7.6.jar;C:\Users\hs\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jackson\jackson-core-asl\1.9.13\jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar;C:\Users\hs\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jackson\jackson-mapper-asl\1.9.13\jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar;C:\Users\hs\.m2\repository\com\thoughtworks\paranamer\paranamer\2.3\paranamer-2.3.jar;C:\Users\hs\.m2\repository\org\xerial\snappy\snappy-java\1.0.5\snappy-java-1.0.5.jar;C:\Users\hs\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-compress\1.4.1\commons-compress-1.4.1.jar;C:\Users\hs\.m2\repository\org\tukaani\xz\1.0\xz-1.0.jar;C:\Users\hs\.m2\repository\commons-lang\commons-lang\2.6\commons-lang-2.6.jar;C:\Users\hs\.m2\repository\org\apache\velocity\velocity\1.7\velocity-1.7.jar;C:\Users\hs\.m2\repository\commons-collections\commons-collections\3.2.1\commons-collections-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\hs\.m2\repository\com\yammer\metrics\metrics-annotation\2.2.0\metrics-annotation-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\hs\.m2\repository\com\yammer\metrics\metrics-core\2.2.0\metrics-core-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\hs\.m2\repository\org\apache\kafka\kafka_2.10\0.8.1.1\kafka_2.10-0.8.1.1.jar;C:\Users\hs\.m2\repository\org\apache\zookeeper\zookeeper\3.3.4\zookeeper-3.3.4.jar;C:\Users\hs\.m2\repository\log4j\log4j\1.2.15\log4j-1.2.15.jar;C:\Users\hs\.m2\repository\javax\mail\mail\1.4\mail-1.4.jar;C:\Users\hs\.m2\repository\javax\activation\activation\1.1\activation-1.1.jar;C:\Users\hs\.m2\repository\javax\jms\jms\1.1\jms-1.1.jar;C:\Users\hs\.m2\repository\com\sun\jdmk\jmxtools\1.2.1\jmxtools-1.2.1.jar;C:\Users\hs\.m2\repository\com\sun\jmx\jmxri\1.2.1\jmxri-1.2.1.jar;C:\Users\hs\.m2\repository\jline\jline\0.9.94\jline-0.9.94.jar;C:\Users\hs\.m2\repository\net\sf\jopt-simple\jopt-simple\3.2\jopt-simple-3.2.jar;C:\Users\hs\.m2\repository\org\scala-lang\scala-library\2.10.1\scala-library-2.10.1.jar;C:\Users\hs\.m2\repository\com\101tec\zkclient\0.3\zkclient-0.3.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.6\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain com.agillic.dialogue.kafka.outbound.SpringKafkaTest
15:39:11.736 [main] INFO  o.s.i.k.support.ProducerFactoryBean - Using producer properties => {metadata.broker.list=172.16.1.42:9092, compression.codec=0}
2015-02-19 15:39:12 INFO  VerifiableProperties:68 - Verifying properties
2015-02-19 15:39:12 INFO  VerifiableProperties:68 - Property compression.codec is overridden to 0
2015-02-19 15:39:12 INFO  VerifiableProperties:68 - Property metadata.broker.list is overridden to 172.16.1.42:9092
15:39:12.164 [main] INFO  o.s.b.f.config.PropertiesFactoryBean - Loading properties file from URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/hs/.m2/repository/org/springframework/integration/spring-integration-core/4.1.2.RELEASE/spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/META-INF/spring.integration.default.properties]
15:39:12.208 [main] DEBUG o.s.i.k.o.KafkaProducerMessageHandler - org.springframework.integration.kafka.outbound.KafkaProducerMessageHandler@5204db6b received message: GenericMessage [payload=foo, headers={timestamp=1424356752208, id=00c483d9-ecf8-2937-4a2c-985bd3afcae4, topic=test-cass, messagekey=3}]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.integration.kafka.outbound.KafkaProducerMessageHandler@5204db6b]; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:84)
    at com.agillic.dialogue.kafka.outbound.SpringKafkaTest.main(SpringKafkaTest.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.support.KafkaProducerContext.getTopicConfiguration(KafkaProducerContext.java:58)
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.support.KafkaProducerContext.send(KafkaProducerContext.java:190)
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.outbound.KafkaProducerMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(KafkaProducerMessageHandler.java:81)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78)
    ... 6 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: I found the solution but Spring team needs to fix this issue. If you prefix the topic with kafka_ in the message header it will work.

Comment: I have a similar problem, Can somebody help with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41117631/spring-integration-kafka-outbound-channel-adapter-send-message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually when we introduced `KafkaHeaders` we did appropriate documentation changes: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-kafka/blob/master/README.md. See Important note:

> Since the last Milestone, we have introduced the KafkaHeaders interface with constants. The messageKey and topic default headers now require a kafka_ prefix. When migrating from an earlier version, you need to specify message-key-expression="headers.messageKey" and topic-expression="headers.topic" on the , or simply change the headers upstream to the new headers from KafkaHeaders using a  or MessageBuilder. Or, of course, configure them on the adapter if you are using constant values.

**UPDATE**

Regarding `NullPointerException`: it's really an issue. Feel free to raise a [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INTEXT) ticket and we'll take care of that. We are even welcome for the [contribution](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md)!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. After using KafkaHeaders, the issue is resolved.